# Implement ondraglister on an imageview inside Viewpager inside collapsibletoolbar inside appbarlayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, ontouch

Has anyone tried to implement an ondrag listener on an imageview inside Viewpager inside collapsibletoolbar inside appbarlayout. The ondrag method is not being called in the ontouchlistener.I tried it for viewpager and appbarlayout.
I need to implement a pulldown for a viewpager inside collapsible toolbar which is inside appbarlayout which is inside a co-ordinator layout. I tried the callback to touch listener on viewpager and on appbar but the move actions are returning false from coordinator layout methods.Has anyone tried something similar?

Thanks